# Conceptual understanding of the phonon and its mode

Tags: solid-state-physics, phonons

As stated in Wikipedia, the phonon is a quasiparticle, it's the representative of the collective oscillation of the particles which build a crystal. These particles can be atoms, ions etc. The oscillations of the atoms and the spread of these oscillations through the medium, can be associated with a wave, which is characterized by a wavevector $\vec k$, frequency $\omega$ and a wavelength $\lambda$. These values also characterize the phonon.

The energy of a single phonon is:

$$E=\hbar\omega$$

While the energy of a phonon mode is:

$$E=\hbar\omega(n+ \frac 1 2)$$.

I have three questions for which I am not sure whether I have the proper understanding or not:

1 - What do we mean when we say "Excited phonon mode". What's physically/visually or in any other form different between a phonon mode in a non-excited state and one in an excited state? To my understanding an excited phonon mode must imply that $n\neq 0$, which means that in the crystal we have phonons belonging to this mode, which physically is translated a change in the amplitude of the oscillation of the atoms. The higher the n value the larger the amplitude, or the displacement of the atoms from their equilibrium position.

2 - Can $n$ be considered as the number of phonons belonging to a mode with a a specific $\vec k$ and $\omega$ value? Is the physical interpretation, a larger displacement of the atoms from their equilibrium position?

3 - The thing I fail to understand is how we associate the energy of a phonon mode with that of the quantum harmonic oscillator. I understand that the atoms themselves behave in such a way, that we can consider them as harmonic oscillators. But if the phonon energy is of the form $E=\hbar\omega$, would it make sense to say that the energy of the mode is $E=\hbar\omega n$? I am aware of the zero point energy of the system. But what I am trying to understand is how we associate  the mode, which is the collective oscillation with a quantum harmonic oscillator.

Comment: A classical pendulum can be at rest, in which case it is non-excited or it can be moving, in which case it is excited and oscillating at a certain frequency. The same applies here. Either the solid has an excited mechanical oscillation mode at a certain frequency (and a wave vector) or it doesn't. The description of phonons with quantum harmonic oscillators is a linear approximation. The mechanical motions of solids are non-linear, which means that we would have to talk about scattering if we wanted to describe them "correctly". That's too complicated for an introduction to phonons.

Comment: But an excitation means $n\neq 0$, But even if you have $n=0$, for an arbitrary frequency mode, you have ground state energy of that mode, meaning, since the phonon mode is not zero, than the corresponding oscillation to it, still occurs in the lattice. Right? That must mean that even if we have no phonons belonging to the mode, the corresponding oscillation still takes place

Comment: The "ground state energy" of a solid is its rest mass, which is many orders of magnitude larger than the harmonic oscillator ground state energy in the linear phonon approximation. I would, in general, warn you against taking the quantum mechanical ground state energy concept too seriously. Energy is the ability of a system to perform work on another system. The calculated ground state energy can't be used to perform work.